# C++ Polymorphism- call derived class method with different signature

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am making an ecosystem simulation in C++. In it there are animals that can be herbivores or carnivores.

Carnivores only eat other herbivores, so when carnivores `eat()`, they must know the direction of the herbivore.

Herbivores only eat grass, so they need not know the direction of anything, they simply eat whats underneath them.as

```
class ANIMAL
{
public:
ANIMAL(...)
: ...
{
}
virtual ~ANIMAL()
{}

//does nothing, just stating that every animal must implement an Eat() method
virtual void Eat() = 0; 
};

class HERBIVORE : public ANIMAL
{
public:
HERBIVORE(...)
: ANIMAL(...)
{}
void Eat(CELL field[40][30], int x, int y);
};


class CARNIVORE : public ANIMAL
{
public:
CARNIVORE(...)
: ANIMAL(...)
{}

void Eat(CELL field[40][30], int x, int y, char direction);
};
```

The function definitions are as follows:

```
void HERBIVORE::Eat(CELL field[40][30], int x, int y)
{
}

void CARNIVORE::Eat(CELL field[40][30], int x, int y, char direction)
{
}
```

When using `virtual`, dynamic-binding is used, so the compiler resolves the function call at run-time. But how can I get around to write code like this:

```
  if (dynamic_cast<CARNIVORE*>(this_animal))    //if carnivore
     this_animal->Eat(field, i, j, direction);

   if (dynamic_cast<HERBIVORE*>(this_animal))   //if herbivore
     this_animal->Eat(field, i, j);
```

without getting this error ?

**Problem:**

I am getting an error:

> 'ANIMAL::Eat': function does not take 3 arguments
>
> 'ANIMAL::Eat': function does not take 4 arguments

It is referring to the base class Eat() which takes no arguments

Comment: This line `if (dynamic_cast<CARNIVORE*>(this_animal))` is what should make you reconsider your design. My two cents.

Comment: I think, that virtual function must have same signature - I'll check the docs.

Comment: If you want to override a virtual function it must have the same signature

Comment: `this_animal` is an `ANIMAL*`. If you want to use the subclass interfaces you need a pointer to the actual type. (But what is the "direction" of a herbivore? Can carnivores only eat herbivores facing north or something?)

Comment: @molbdnilo I have an algorithm not shown that returns the character L,R,U, or D of the nearest herbivore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use the dynamic cast only to check the class. `this_animal` is still a pointer to ANIMAL and does hence have no Eat function.

To solve your issue, you have to use the dynamic cast until the end:

```
 if (dynamic_cast<CARNIVORE*>(this_animal))    //if carnivore
     dynamic_cast<CARNIVORE*>(this_animal)->Eat(field, i, j, direction); // 4 args

 if (dynamic_cast<HERBIVORE*>(this_animal))   //if herbivore
     dynamic_cast<CARNIVORE*>(this_animal)->Eat(field, i, j);  // 3 args
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I was missing the second dynamic cast. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your classes do not currently override the pure virtual method in the base class. Any virtual overrides should have the same signature as the base class declaration. An easy way to solve the problem is make all overloads have access to the direction, with a definition like the following:

```
void Eat(CELL field[40][30], int x, int y, char direction)
{
    ...
}
```

This way the overloads that need the direction have it, and the ones that don't need it can ignore it. Also, no `dynamic_cast`s are necessary.

Comment: This answer is how one approaches virtual polymorphism -- avoid dynamic_cast if possible (especially two of them), set up a uniform interface (maybe use a "right here" direction), and don't use dynamic_cast to determine a class' traits, requiring the calling code to be aware of each available derived class. Instead, give the class a way to check for traits. like calling EatsAnimals() and EatsGrass(), then if you add OMNIVORE one day, you might not need to refactor all of your app's code, like you would if it weren't using any "polymorphism" at all.